# Python list intersection condition

Tags: python

So, I have a list of some letters and symbols and another list of just symbols.

```
list1=['A','B','!']
list2=['!','?','.']
```

Then I have to modify every element of list1 by using some shift value. but I have to make it so that shift value will only affect elements that are not in list2! So, 'A' and 'B' would change, but '!' would be unaffected. How can I do that?

Comment: What kind of shift?  Is this a homework question?

Comment: Is the "shift" modulo some finite sequence, e.g., 8-bit ASCII codes?

Comment: Yes, it is a homework question, but I don't want to post it all.
Shift is just an integer that user inputs. It's supposed to either increase or decrease ascii values of letters. This is not my problem right now. My problem is that god damn list intersection. Basically, what's supposed to happen is every letter must be affected by shift, but special symbols must not.

Comment: @user2961792 I've updated my answer to do it in place without list comprehensions. Is there something preventing you from using it?

Comment: @sdasdadas I'm still learning myself, but it was my understanding that iterating over a list and modifying it simultaneously was bad practice.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @thumbtackthief No, you're probably right. Even if it works out ok (because you're not changing the length or the type of value stored?) it seems more "pythonic" to use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = [chr((ord(x) + shift) % 256) if x not in list2 else x for x in list1 ]
```

EDIT:

If you're not comfortable with list comprehensions yet:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    char1 = list1[i]
    if char1 not in list2:
        list1[i] = chr((ord(char1) + shift) % 256)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without creating new list?

Comment: @user2961792 Yes, just overwrite your old list.

Comment: @alko Thanks, I think that fixes it (assuming ASCII).

Comment: it might also be a good idea to make list2 a set for efficiency

Comment: @JoelGreen I don't think the OP will be concerned about optimization.

Comment: Hmmm, assuming the same code will be used to "unshift" the list, perhaps two (or more) partitions of the ASCII sequence are required.  Otherwise it's possible that "shifted" letters will become punctuation that will not get "unshifted" later.